# How can implement synchronous Ajax call using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to implement synchronous Ajax calling mechanism. I already implement ajax calling function in my helper same as below :

```
MH.helper = {
    ajax : function (option) {
        if(option !== undefined) {
            for(var opt in option) {
                this[opt] = option[opt];
            }
        }

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            this.xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            this.xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
}
```

I also implement Ajax prototype as same as below :

```
MH.helper.ajax.prototype = {
    // XMLHttpRequest obj
    xhr : null,

    // request url
    url: '',

    // post funciton
    post: function() {

    var xhr = this.xhr;
    var that = this;

    xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            if(that.complete && ( typeof that.complete === 'function' )) {
                that.complete(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    }

    var data = MH.helper.serialize(this.data, true);

    xhr.open("POST",this.url,true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(data);
},

// get funciton
get: function() {

    var xhr = this.xhr;
    var that = this;

    xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            if(that.complete && ( typeof that.complete === 'function' )) {
                that.complete(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    }

    var data = MH.helper.serialize(this.data);
    xhr.open("GET",this.url+data,true);
    xhr.send(data);
},

// callback when request done
complete: null
}
```

Anyone have any idea how can I implement synchronous call using my Ajax function?

Comment: Don't do that.  Synchronous requests will freeze the browser.

Comment: @SLaks I know that. But I want to diversity in my function.

Comment: Don't do that anyway.

Comment: @monsur.hoq - FYI, the A in AJAX stands for "Asynchronous"

Comment: @SLaks In case of before unload event you have no option without synchronous Ajax calling.

Comment: @O.O `jQuery.ajax` also implement an attribute `async:false` its require in many case e.g. [click this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

Comment: @monsur.hoq - so then just use jQuery.  No need to reinvent the wheel, is there? :)

Comment: @O.O It's require. Why I need to use full jQuery library for a simple Ajax calling from third parties site to my site e.g. content sharing service

Comment: @O.O "*No need to reinvent the wheel, is there? :)*" but the OP just wants to know how to build a synchronous XHR call – not the whole wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `false` as the third argument of `xhr.open`.

Sources: [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open%28%29-method), [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

Comment: Wrong -> it will kill most devices.

Comment: @lin it may not be recommended, but it isn't *"wrong"*

Comment: Agree! Edit: This will kill most devices. Especially the mobile one :)

Comment: @lin the OP is specifically asking *how* to force synchronous XHR – not *if* that's a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

```
xhr.open("POST",this.url,true)
```

If you pass `false` as the 3rd parameter instead of `true` - the call will be performed synchronously.

But my advice - don't. Use callback functions always.

Comment: It is not always possible to use callbacks. You have to have your entire interface prepared for asynchronous calls, which is not always true.